# How can I access a variable in beaforeEach using cy.wrap

Tags: cypress

I have this piece of code and when I run it it says "undefined reading 'auth'". What am I doing wrong here? I read the documentation and it should be working?

```
beforeEach(() => {
        cy.login(email).then((token) => {
            let headers = { "x-access-token": token }
            cy.wrap(headers).as("auth")
        })
    })

    it("Buy " + par, () => {
        if (stables.indexOf(par) < 0) {
            cy.request({
                method: "POST",
                url: url,
                headers: this.auth,
                body: payloadBUYToken,
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.*` notation is available in a function callback only but your code uses an arrow one.

Here is the corrected variant:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
        cy.login(email).then((token) => {
            let headers = { "x-access-token": token }
            cy.wrap(headers).as("auth")
        })
    })

    it("Buy " + par, function() {
        if (stables.indexOf(par) < 0) {
            cy.request({
                method: "POST",
                url: url,
                headers: this.auth,
                body: payloadBUYToken,
            })
        }
```

See [this article](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/avoid-cypress-pyramid-of-doom/) for details